# Rearranging the placement of monitors to persist after restart?

Tags: ubuntu, configuration, monitors, multi-monitor, settings

I am using Ubuntu 16LTS and the default setting for the extended monitor via HDMI is on the right but mine is on the left. I set it to the left, and on restarting it begins again on the right. How can the change be maintained?

I have altered the `/.config/monitors.xml` file to make some persistance in the placement / orientation of the monitors relative to each other. Within this file there is the main `<monitors>` tag, and within it two `<configuration>` tags where in the first is only the laptop monitor and in the second the eDP1 and HDMI1 output for the extended monitor.

In the monitors.xml file, I have the laptop monitor's primary mark as no:

```
<primary>no</primary>
```

The monitor attached via HDMI is set to primary in the file:

```
<primary>yes</primary>
```

This was the other way around before making the edit. For the laptop monitor there is the `<x>` tag which is set to `<x>0</x>` and I switched this to `<x>1920</x>` and zero for the extended monitor hoping this would work.

How do I get this setting to remain/persist?